# Fancybox jquery multiple popup boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am using this http://fancybox.net/example for my code.

```
<a id="view1" href="#box1">Click1</a>

<div id="box1" style="display:none;">
<a id="view2" href="#box2">Click2</a>
</div>

<div id="box2" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

I implement fancybox on `a#view1` and `a#view2` so that when people click on `Click1` it will open fancybox. Then if they click on `Click2` button within that fancybox, it will open box2. I want to do it as if the shape of box1 "transform" into shape of box2 but I could not do it. Although I think what I can do is to hide `box1` and show `box2`, it is not desired. Can someone help?

Comment: Sorry I figure out how. Basically, I use livequery to make the new button take fancybox action. 

Close this question!

Answer (score -2):

you will need to place jquery code to close/hide the required layer. BTW, if you use Thickbox, life might be more easier, as it has wider community

Comment: FYI - According to the thickbox website, they closed development on this on 9/30/2009... A couple months before your post.  Interestingly they recommended fancybox as a replacement.  Although that hasn't been updated since november of 2009.  grr